# Convert String value to date in R

Tags: r

I have a table as follows:

```
Year  Appearances
18/19     4
18/19     5
17/18     10
17/18     13
16/17     22
16/17     19
```

Is there a way for me to convert the 18/19 to 2019?

And also is there a way to add all the 'Appearances' for each year up? My perfect output table would be:

```
Year  Appearances
2019     9
2018     23
2017     41
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can remove one or more digits (`\\d+`) at the start (`^`) followed by a `/` (with `str_remove`) concatenate with "20" (`str_c`), use that as a grouping variable and get the `sum` of 'Appearances'

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(Year = str_c("20", str_remove(Year, "^\\d+\\/"))) %>% 
  summarise(Appearances = sum(Appearances))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  Year  Appearances
#  <chr>       <int>
#1 2017           41
#2 2018           23
#3 2019            9
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Year = c("18/19", "18/19", "17/18", "17/18", "16/17", 
"16/17"), Appearances = c(4L, 5L, 10L, 13L, 22L, 19L)), 
   class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -6L))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use this one-liner from base R.

```
aggregate(
    Appearances ~ Year, 
    transform(df, Year = sub(".*/(.*)", "20\\1", Year)), 
    sum
)
#   Year Appearances
# 1 2017          41
# 2 2018          23
# 3 2019           9
```

Answer (score 0):

A different `dplyr` possibility using `sub()` could be:

```
df %>%
 group_by(Year = paste0("20", sub(".*/", "", Year))) %>%
 summarise_all(sum)

  Year  Appearances
  <chr>       <int>
1 2017           41
2 2018           23
3 2019            9
```

It extracts the characters after `/` and combines them with 20.

Or using `substr()`:

```
df %>%
 group_by(Year = paste0("20", substr(Year, nchar(Year)-1, nchar(Year)))) %>%
 summarise_all(sum)
```

Here it extracts the last two characters from "Year" and combines them with 20.